# Django db name 'connection' is not defined

Tags: python, mysql, django

i'm making my first project in django + mysql, the problem here is it's notify me that the name 'connection' is not defined. I don't know why. Can't anyone explain me?
from django.db import connections
import cv2

def detect(request):

```
faceDetect = cv2.CascadeClassifier(BASE_DIR + '/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# creating recognizer
rec = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create();
# loading the training data
rec.read(BASE_DIR + '/recognizer/trainingData.yml')
getId = 0
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
maSv = 0
while(True):
    ret, img = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)

        getId,conf = rec.predict(gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]) #This will predict the id of the face

        #print conf;
        if conf<35:
            maSv = getId
            cv2.putText(img, str(maSv),(x,y+h), font, 2, (0,255,0),2)
            maSV = str(maSv)
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.callproc('diemdanh', [maSV, '101B1'])
        else:
            cv2.putText(img, "Unknown",(x,y+h), font, 2, (0,0,255),2)

        # Printing that number below the face
        # @Prams cam image, id, location,font style, color, stroke

    cv2.imshow("Face",img)
    if(cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q')):
        break
    elif(maSv != 0):
        cv2.waitKey(1000)
        cam.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        return redirect('/')

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Not the database, the variable `connection` itself is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported **connection** ?

Try:

```
from django.db import connection
```